# Figure out client IP used

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I have a linux box that for strange reasons has two IP addresses on the same physical network interface, and both IPs are in the same subnet. The machine is reachable via both IPs, and everything seems to work as normal.

Until I discovered there is a NAS service this machine needs to consume. And this NAS has been locked down based on IP. Since the addition of the second IP it seems no more possible to mount the NAS share. One obvious fix would be to remove the IP limitation or add the second IP.

My question is: If a machine has multiple IPs, which one is it going to use for sending traffic? Or in other words, what would be client IP a server would see if this dual-IPed machine acts as client?

Edit: I now learned some client applications can specify which interface to use for outgoing traffic. This is new to me. So my client would be

- NFS mount (`mount -t nfs ...`)
- ping

How can I specify the IP for outgoing traffic?
If the client application does not specify, how does the OS choose?
Can the OS choice for outgoing traffic be biased towards one, the other or both interfaces?

Comment: Technically the client app can chose for itself.  If the app doesn't specify, then the OS selects one.  So without going into how the OS selects an IP automatically, it would be worth checking the client options to see if you can specify it.  If you are interested in answers to that effect you could [edit] your question to include how you connect to your NAS (which client).

Comment: The simpler way to fix that would be to fix configuration so that it only has one IP address. Having two IP addresses can cause all kind of headaches, as you have discovered. One potential reason for having two IP addresses is that you have to DHCP clients running, possibly from different services.

Comment: @dirkt That's not true at all!  There's any number of reasons for legitimately having two IPs on one interface.  Pretty much any internet facing server that's *not* behind a NAT will have both public and private IPs on the same interface.  Two IPs per interface is almost **mandatory** under IPv6.  IPv6 requires a link-local ip address as well as any other internet routable address or locally routable address.  Calling this configuration "broken" is plainly wrong.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri I've updated my answer, you can just set the `clientaddr` option.

Comment: @PhilipCouling two IPs on one interface might be ok, two IPs from the **same** subnet on the same interface ... probably you have a better way to set up the network.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Again, no.  There are two many reasons to have multiple IPs to list them all.  Another example is that you want to run two instances of the same service on the same machine.  HTTP achieves this with the "HOST" header but many other protocols must have two IPs or use non standard ports.

Comment: I initially described that there are two IPs on the same subnet for a strange reason. When I setup that server, I simply used DHCP to configure the box, and the DHCP server is configured to always assign the same IP. Meanwhile I found out it's better to have a static IP and configured it. Removing DHCP will at the moment also kill my DNS entry so for the time being I keep both IPs until I have a better solution. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I am talking IPv4, not IPv6. IPv6 is built right from the start to allow multiple addresses, and it also has a mechanism to choose the right one depending on the destination. IPv4 doesn't.

Comment: @dirkt no, for the sake of this question the problem is identical for ipv4 and ipv6.  It's not even caused by having 2ips on one interface, it's caused by having two IPs on one **client box** and the server being picky about which one is used.  Two IPs on one interface is absolute **normal** outside home networking.  This has always been. The case even before ipv6

Comment: The problem could even arise with IPs on different networks. Just imagine there are multiple routes to the destination server. An explicitly desired state that makes the internet resilient - as intended in the old DARPA days...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When any client tries to start a connection, it can either specify its own client IP or it can use the address `INADDR_ANY` (AKA: `0.0.0.0`) as the source address.  If INADDR_ANY is used then Linux automatically selects an address when the client calls [connect()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) - see [man 7 ip](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html).

---

**The easiest fix** is to tell your client which IP to select.

As you've mounted with `mount -t nfs ...` you can just set the `clientaddr` option (see [man 5 nfs](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs)).  If the IP you want is 10.20.30.41 you just add the option with:

```
... -o clientaddr=10.20.30.41 ...`
```

Or if you already have an `-o` then you just comma separate your other options.  Change

```
... -o foo=bar
```

to

```
... -o foo=bar,clientaddr=10.20.30.41
```

---

**If you can't stop your client using INADDR_ANY** then ...

From what I read, the source address is set by the `src` address on the routing table.  See [man 8 ip route](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-route.8.html)

So Linux checks the remote (NAS) IP that you're trying to connect to, then looks up the address in its routing table.  It selects the `src` address that's specified there.

At the terminal you can view your routing table with `ip route` and get something like this:

```
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.143 metric 600 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-ff4f53a0f3b5 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 
172.22.0.0/16 dev br-66358811b693 proto kernel scope link src 172.22.0.1 linkdown 
172.29.0.0/16 dev br-ce3d9cbbad0b proto kernel scope link src 172.29.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.143 
192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.143 metric 600
```

Here you can see that if you try to connect to anything `172.17.x.x` Linux will select `172.17.0.1` as the source address.  Likewise, anything on the public internet will go through the "default route" so it would select `192.168.1.143`.

You can modify your routing table with `ip route add ...`, `ip route change ...` and `ip route del ...`.

I would suggest you make the smallest change possible to your routing table to avoid other problems.  You create a route for a single IP and it will take priority over the route for the whole subnet. For example if the LAN is 10.20.30.0/24, the system's secondary IP address is 10.20.30.22 also on interface *eth0* and the NAS also in this LAN is using 10.20.30.31:

```
ip route add 10.20.30.31/32 dev eth0 src 10.20.30.22
```

or if the NAS is in another network with address 172.20.30.31 reachable through the gateway 10.20.30.1:

```
ip route add 172.20.30.31/32 via 10.20.30.1 src 10.20.30.22
```

*Warning: I've not had chance to test the above.*

Comment: I'd do the same as in the end of your answer. Solved in one shot. But, I don't see the point in the example of "via 10.20.30.21" when it's obviously about systems in the same LAN, so no gateway involved here. Without via, specifying the interface is mandatory though.

Comment: @A.B.   I couldn't get to a Linux terminal to check what I wrote. If you'd like to offer an edit I'll check it and accept.  That said there's nothing in the question to say the NAS is on the same subnet, so this answer perhaps needs both forms.

Comment: I made the change as you allowed me, with a 2nd example using a gateway. With more obvious addresses choices. Of course feel free to change it further or back.

Comment: Very good description. Thank you, Philip.

Comment: The problem with "telling the client which one to select" is that not all applications support command line options to let you do this. On top, it's very painful to do that if the call is deep within some other software. It's really really much simpler to just use one IPv4 address per network segment. You *can* make multiple addresses work, but there's no obvious upside, and it's a PITA to get right. If you **need** multiple IPv4 addresses for some reason, use network namespaces.

Comment: @dirkt Please don't spread mis-information. Think first!  What you are saying doesn't add up. Firstly the clientaddr option isn't there randomly, someone spent time and effort adding it and documenting it. When you look around it's a really common software option.  Secondly the issue the OP is having is **nothing** to do with having multiple IPs on the same interface.  It is caused by having multiple IPs on the **box** and the server will only accept one of them.  How is that different to having wifi and then plugging in ethernet?  **It isn't!!!*.

Comment: @dirkt I even explained in the answer what to do if your client application doesn't let you specify an IP.

Comment: When I tried the suggestions I found out that the new static IP is preferred over the dynamic one. Somehow I had expected that anyway. But adding the client IP for the mount was not good enough. So I removed restrictions on the NAS and saw connectivity come back. Investigating some more I saw that the system preferred to use IPv6. The NAS had been configured for an IPv6 anyway BUT MY CLIENT IPV6 had changed. With this I also found https://serverfault.com/questions/93717/setting-ipv4-as-preferred-protocol-over-ipv6